# Spark SQL sum function issues on double value

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

We are trying to sum the double values using Spark SQL sum function.

**Sample Data:**

```
+------+
|amount|
+------+
|  1000|
|  1050|
|  2049|
+------+
```

**sample Code:**

```
df.select("amount").show();
df.registerTempTable("table");
sqlContext.sql("select amount/pow(10,2) from table").show();
sqlContext.sql("select sum((amount/pow(10,2))) from table").show();
```

**After precision:**

```
+-----+
|  _c0|
+-----+
| 10.0|
| 10.5|
|20.49|
+-----+
```

**Output After Sum:**

```
+------------------+
|               _c0|
+------------------+
|40.989999999999995|
+------------------+
```

The exected output  is `40.99` , but why its giving output as `40.989999999999995`.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I don't know spark but that seems to be another example of [floating point precision](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) issues.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for the information.. is there any workaround?

Comment: Hmm, as I said I don't know Spark but in Java I'd either round the values (maybe adding 0.001 or some other epsilon first) or use `BigDecimal` or even integer-only math. I'm not sure what spark supports but you could try to rewrite your query to use integer-math as long as possible, i.e. `select sum(amount)/pow(10,2) from table` or even `select sum(amount)/100 from table`.

Comment: @Thomas: Seems this one is working `select sum(amount)/pow(10,2) from table`, thanks so much.. let me test more scenarios..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the sum is evaluated as [decimal](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) (Spark SQL mapping).

eg: `select sum( cast(amount as decimal)  / cast(pow(10,2) as decimal) ) from table`

I would recommend you convert amount to be of type decimal.

Comment: Thanks, its working, but its printing `40.99000000000`

Comment: If you want to round the number then use the [round function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@round(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,scale:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).